# Javascript Generate and Print JSON from dynamic input values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, dynamic

I want to do this without using Jquery, in pure Javascript. All the examples I found are using JQuery.

I have an html page (index.html) with ,

```
<form id="1">
 <input type="text">10</input>
 <input type="text">20</input>
</form>

<form id="2">
 <input type="text">55</input>
 <input type="text">66</input>
</form>
```

I want to print this in another page (data.json) like this,

```
[
    {
        "1": [
            "10",
            "20"
        ],
        "2": [
            "55",
            "66"
        ]
    }
]
```

In a separate file (makejson.js) I have a JQuery syntax that I want to change to pure Javascript,

```
function makeJSON() {
jsonObj = [];
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {

    var inData = $(this).val();

    item = {}
    item ["1"] = inData;

    jsonObj.push(item);
  });
}
```

This currently doesn't work and it is only for the array coming from the "1" parameter (form id 1). I need something able to loop dynamically (i.e. "i = 0; i < array.length; i++" ) that determines array 1 coming from form id 1 and array 2 coming from form id 2.

How can I collect inputs, convert them to JSON and save them to a separate page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain Javascript solution:

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ws5KZ/2/)**

```
function makeJSON(){
    var arr = [{}];
    var inputs;
    var jsonString;

    var forms = document.forms;
    for(var i=0; i<forms.length; i++){

        if(typeof(arr[0][forms[i].id]) == 'undefined'){
          arr[0][forms[i].id] = [];
        }

        for(var ii=0; ii<forms[i].elements.length; ii++){
          arr[0][forms[i].id].push(forms[i].elements[ii].value)
        }

    }

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
    console.log(jsonString);
}
```

Outputs a JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "1": [
            "10",
            "20"
        ],
        "2": [
            "55",
            "66"
        ]
    }
]
```